# Where can I find more information on Core Data?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data

I am having a hard time understand Core Data for cocoa. Now I have read a couple different books regarding programming on OS X and I get the fundamentals of Core data, creating a model and accessing the information through key bindings of interface builder; but now I am looking for information about how to access the information through code like to be able to compare an object to all the others to make sure there isn't any duplicates.

Now I have tried reading apple's guide and it is still little over my head (I am still a beginner). But if someone could point to a good tutorial that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several guides besides the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/) that are relevant:

- [Model Object Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/)
- [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/)
- [Creating a Managed Object Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CreatingMOMWithXcode/)
- [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/)

I got the last two from the “Related Documents” section of the CDPG.

Not quite so Core Data/data-modeling related, but still useful for applying Core Data, are the documents on using Bindings:

- [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/)
- [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/)
- [Cocoa Bindings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/)

Bindings makes it easier to use built-in Cocoa views to display the data you keep in your model.

You'll also find the framework references worth bookmarking:

- [Foundation Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/)
- [Application Kit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/)
- [Core Data Framework reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/)

Answer (score 3):

Marcus S. Zarra's "Core Data" book gets good reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I learned by actually doing. [This is where I started](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php). It's a pretty good tutorial.

Edit: I forgot two other tutorials I followed:

[Part 1](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.07/CoreData/)

[Part 2](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.09/CoreDataII/)

Comment: Your link didn't come through